# Consumir WebService Rest(curl) con autenticación y FormData en java

Tags: php, java, rest, java-ee, curl

Invoco un web service rest con la siguiente sección de código en php:

```
            echo $ejercicio."\n";
            echo $claveUpa."\n";
            echo $tipoDocumento."\n";
            echo $numero."\n";
            echo $numeroSoporte."\n";
            echo $nomArchivoCompleto."\n";
            $cliente=curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt($cliente,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"POST");
            curl_setopt($cliente,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode($u.":".$pass),"accept: */*"));
            $cfile = curl_file_create(__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$nomcarpeta.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$nomArchivoCompleto,"application/pdf",$archivo);
            $postData = array(
                //"fileData"  => $cfile,
                "ejercicio" => $ejercicio,
                "claveUpa"  => $claveUpa,
                "tipoDocumento"=>$tipoDocumento,
                "numero" => $numero,
                "tipoDocumental" =>"1"
            );
            //$entrada = json_encode($postData);
            curl_setopt($cliente, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
            curl_setopt($cliente,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
            $respuesta=curl_exec($cliente);
            echo "------\n";
            $codigo=curl_getinfo($cliente,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            curl_close($cliente);
```

En postman esa misma invocación me genera el siguiente comando:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://url/rest/api/v1/patronato/subirPoliza' \
--header 'accept: */*' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic cmVwcm9jZXNvX3BvbGl6YXM6YyUxdUZFJjZpNGN0b3Jj' \
--form 'ejercicio="2022"' \
--form 'claveUpa="CFI"' \
--form 'tipoDocumento="02"' \
--form 'numero="000222"' \
--form 'tipoDocumental="1"' \
--form 'fileData=@"/C:/path/2022-CFI-02-000222.pdf"'
```

Lo que quiero es poder consumir el mismo web service pero desde java, pero no he podido encontrar la manera de pasar los parámetros --form. Primero estuve obteniendo el error 415 de http y ahora después de modificar unas cosas obtengo un error 400. Mi código esta basado en lo que encontré en [esta página](https://blog.cpming.top/p/httpurlconnection-multipart-form-data).

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;
public class HttpPostMultipart {
    private final String boundary;
    private static final String LINE = "\r\n";
    private HttpURLConnection httpConn;
    private String charset;
    private OutputStream outputStream;
    private PrintWriter writer;
    public HttpPostMultipart(String requestURL, String charset, Map<String, String> headers,String usr,String pass) throws IOException {
        this.charset = charset;
        boundary = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        URL url = new URL(requestURL);
        httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
        httpConn.setDoOutput(true);    // indicates POST method
        httpConn.setDoInput(true);
        String authString = usr + ":" + pass;
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Basic "+Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(
                (authString).getBytes()
            ));
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36");
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
        if (headers != null && headers.size() > 0) {
            Iterator<String> it = headers.keySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                String key = it.next();
                String value = headers.get(key);
                httpConn.setRequestProperty(key, value);
            }
        }
        outputStream = httpConn.getOutputStream();
        writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, charset), true);
    }
    public void addFormField(String name, String value) {
        writer.append("--" + boundary).append(LINE);
        writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + name + "\"").append(LINE);
        writer.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset).append(LINE);
        writer.append(LINE);
        writer.append(value).append(LINE);
        writer.flush();
    }
    public void addFilePart(String fieldName, File uploadFile)
            throws IOException {
        String fileName = uploadFile.getName();
        writer.append("--" + boundary).append(LINE);
        writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + fieldName + "\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"").append(LINE);
        writer.append("Content-Type: " + URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fileName)).append(LINE);
        writer.append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary").append(LINE);
        writer.append(LINE);
        writer.flush();

        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = -1;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        inputStream.close();
        writer.append(LINE);
        writer.flush();
    }
    public String finish() throws IOException {
        String response = "";
        writer.flush();
        writer.append("--" + boundary + "--").append(LINE);
        writer.close();

        // checks server's status code first
        int status = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        String msg=httpConn.getResponseMessage();
        if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = httpConn.getInputStream().read(buffer)) != -1) {
                result.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            response = result.toString(this.charset);
            httpConn.disconnect();
        } else {
            throw new IOException("Server returned non-OK status: " + status+" - "+msg);
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

Invoco la clase de esta manera:

```
String usuario = "reproceso_polizas";
                            String pass = "c%1uFE&6i4ctorc";
                            String url="http://url/rest/api/v1/patronato/subirPoliza";
                            
                            System.out.println(report.toString());
                            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            //params.put("fileData",report.toString());
                            params.put("ejercicio", "2022");
                            params.put("claveUpa", "ew");
                            params.put("tipoDocumento", "erer");
                            params.put("numero", "df");
                            params.put("tipoDocumental","fdfd");
                            
                            
                            
                            try {
                                // Set header
                                
                                HttpPostMultipart multipart = new HttpPostMultipart(url, "utf-8", params,usuario,pass);
                                
                                String response = multipart.finish();
                                System.out.println(response);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
```

Estoy obteniendo el siguiente error:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned non-OK status: 400 - null
    at subirPolizasAlfresco.HttpPostMultipart.finish(HttpPostMultipart.java:90)
    at subirPolizasAlfresco.Main.procesaArchivo(Main.java:213)
    at subirPolizasAlfresco.Main.main(Main.java:75)
```

Esto es debido a que obtengo un error 400. Alguien puede decirme que estoy haciendo mal. Se que no es la url, ni el usuario, ni la contraseña debido a que en php si me funciona. Es la manera en que paso los datos, pero no se como pasarlos de forma correcta. ¿Alguien puede indicarme que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despues de una semana de sufrir logre resolverlo con la api OkHttp:
Dependencia:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Y este es el código que invoca al WebService Rest con autenticación y paso de parámetros incluyendo un archivo como parámetro:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().build();
MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream");
String ejercicio="20"+polizaPDF.getFecha().substring(0,2);
String claveUpa=polizaPDF.getFolio_poliza().substring(0, 3);
String tipoDocumento=polizaPDF.getFolio_poliza().substring(3, 5);
String numero=polizaPDF.getFolio_poliza().substring(5);
String nombrePolizaCompleto=ejercicio+"-"+claveUpa+"-"+tipoDocumento+"-"+numero;
String nombreArchivoPDF=nombrePolizaCompleto+".pdf";
RequestBody body = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
.addFormDataPart("ejercicio",ejercicio)
.addFormDataPart("claveUpa",claveUpa)
.addFormDataPart("tipoDocumento",tipoDocumento)
.addFormDataPart("numero",numero)
.addFormDataPart("tipoDocumental","1")
.addFormDataPart("fileData",nombreArchivoPDF,RequestBody.create(mediaType, report) )
.build();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
.url(url)
.method("POST", body)
.addHeader("accept", "*/*")
.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(   (authString).getBytes()  ))
.build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
System.out.println(response.code());
String respuesta=response.body().string();
System.out.println("Poliza["+nombrePolizaCompleto+"]=>"+respuesta);
```